# OnScreen keyboard opens automatically when Activity starts

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, scrollview

When my Activity with a `ScrollView` layout and `EditText`s starts, the `EditText`s get focus and the Android OnScreen keyboard opens.

How I can avoid that?

When I was using `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` without the `ScrollView` it doesn't happen.

I've tried it this way, and it works, but it's not a good way to do it:

```
TextView TextFocus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MovileLabel);
TextFocus.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
TextFocus.requestFocus();
```

Next you have an example of some of my layouts with this problem, when this Activity starts, focus goes to the first `EditText`, *Description* and the Android keyboard opens automatically, this is very annoying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:padding="10px">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserLabel" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13px"
                android:text="@string/userlabel"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/User"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/UserLabel"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#808080"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12px"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionLabel" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/desclabel"
            android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
            <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/Description"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/DescriptionLabel"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="180px"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EmailLabel" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/emaillabel"
                android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/Email"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EmailLabel"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="180px"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MovilePhoneLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/movilephonelabel"
                android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/MovilePhone"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/MovilePhoneLabel"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="180px"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#808080"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10px"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/applybutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/apply"
                android:width="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:width="100px"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/applybutton"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dip"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i test it and yes, if i remove the scrollview from my layout, the android keyboard doesn'ts open automatically!!! the problem it's for the scrollview, but i need it :S can someone help?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Android opens the OnScreenKeyboard automatically if you have an `EditText` focussed when the Activity starts.

You can prevent that by adding following into your Activity's `onCreate` method.

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Does the always hidden part mean it doesn't show up if I tap the EditText?

Comment: @ToothlessRebel : yes..it does!

Comment: I am using this   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" this did not work for me

Answer (score 27):

If you want to do it editing the AndroidManifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".Dades"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

the line `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` is the one that prevents the keyboard focus.

Answer (score 19):

Another way is by adding on LinearLayout:

```
android:focusable="true"

android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Let me indicate that

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

still does the same thing, but the cursor is still there.

Answer (score 1):

This will an inappropriate behaviour

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

but it will do it smoothly(do it in `manifest` for that activity)

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below statement also,

***(EditTextName).setInputType(0)***

it will permanently hides default keyboard of perticular Edittext, even on EditText Touch or Click.

Comment: and how to open the keyboard again ?