# keyboard automatic pops up when moving from one activity to another

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview, window-soft-input-mode

In my application when i go from one activity to another soft keyboard automatically pops up.

i have one activity(Say A) on which i have set

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

because i don't want keyboard on this activity but when i move from this activity to another activity(say B) which contains Map and AutoComompleteTextView, keyboard first automatically pops up and then close down.

what i have tried on activity B:
In manifest i have set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

in oncreate

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

i also tried putting this in OnCreate

```
  try{
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: keyboard crash");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i also tried to set focus on another view in activity like(View v1)

```
 v1.requestFoucs();
```

i even tried putting

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

on each and every component on activity B.

but nothing worked for me.

please help me to solve this problem
i have already tried all the accepted ans that belongs to list of links below:

[OnScreen keyboard opens automatically when Activity starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149415/onscreen-keyboard-opens-automatically-when-activity-starts)

[Automatic popping up keyboard on start Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity)

[How to avoid automatically appear android keyboard when activity start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732761/how-to-avoid-automatically-appear-android-keyboard-when-activity-start)

this is my AutoComompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auto_serviceArea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:hint="@string/serviceArea"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Edit 1: I tried to check that which view is getting focus so i can shift that focus, and while debugging i removed focus from AutoCompleteTextView but still keyboard appears and gone when activity starts.
So this is not an Autocomplete focus problem.

Comment: post your edittext XML layout.

Comment: xml added @ahamed

Comment: @RajatPorwal try `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in autocompleteTextView

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' tried not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried everything that comes as an accepted ans according to your links for the ques, then why don't you try debugging your start activity, i mean on which you have put intent to start the respective activity.
While debugging one of my application i found that android soft keyboard has that problem of not going down even after finishing the activity that calls it, it stays on screen for few seconds but this doesn't happen frequently.

So i suggest you to debug your calling activity too just try putting "focusable=false" on the component from which you called the respective activity.

Comment: but i have put       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"    in my calling activity , which means i have changed the keyboard accessibility on that activity so keyboard will never appear on that screen, Correct me if am wrong.?

Comment: but OK i will try your suggestion because i don't have any other choice , I have tried everything on the current activity.

Comment: i tried debugging the calling activity and as you suggested put focusable=false on the component from which i was calling new activity and
it worked..!! That means problem is on calling activity, keyboard appears on calling activity. I dont know why this happens because i have already put          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            and         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateUnchanged|stateAlwaysHidden" in menifest.xml still that keyboard appears on that activity.
Can you Please Explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Simply what you need to do is to give

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

in Manifest file of your Activity.

Comment: tried not working i even tried "stateAlwaysHidden" but not working

Comment: Remove all other code for Keyboard and just put this Manifest code. Its working fine for me. I always use this method for hiding keyboard on Activity create.

Comment: I found this link quite helpful I hope it helps you too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxdEKTt0-1k

Comment: @AshishVora tried your solution problem remains the same but now keyboard is not coming on touch also.

Comment: When you click on Edittext, keyboard is not coming?

Comment: sorry that because i accidentally put focusable = false on Autocomplete, now keyboard comes on touch but my problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Write below line inside your main xml tag

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

just as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines in `java` file:

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```